# Is "I switched off television because I had exam the very next day." correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> I switched off television because I had exam the very next day.

Had is used for earlier action, so is it correct to use "had" here  ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably "I switched off **the** television because I had **an** exam the very next day."

It is correct to use had but only if you have an afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the changes made in the previous answer.

The grammatically correct sentence should be "I switched off the television because I had an exam the very next day."

I would like to add on that the use of ‘had’ in this sentence means that the entire event happened in the past and you are just recounting the incident now.

If you use ‘have’ instead of ‘had’ in that sentence, it would mean that the event is happening as you say the sentence.